# Linux VM Size show very high in vsphere

Tags: linux, vsphere

We are using vsphere for running our VM environment.

Issue
Some of the Linux VMs show that their size is more then 300GB in the datastore.
But when we checked the dir within the linux systems its show us only 2 directory which are around 50GB each. So total of 100GB.
Rest all Dir are less then 1 GB

So max in total 105 GB I can see within the linux system.
Why does Vsphere show that the size of the VM is 300GB?

Is their any tool or command by which I can see any hidden files or dir, or any other way so that I can see where is this linux vm using all this extra space?

Note:
It got only 1 snapshot.

Comment: You should use `du` and `df` as well as the VM settings (you would be able to see the configured size of the HDD) to check how much space it should be using. Look at the number of snapshots for the VM as well.

Comment: VMware products do not auto-compact thin-provisioned virtual disks. I very much doubt the server products even offer support for compacting disks.

Answer (score 0):

Every time a snapshot is taken it is possible to use up the amount of disk space that the VM was allocated all over again. In your case, this means that if you have allocated 100GB of storage to the VM, your snapshot makes it possible for the system to use up to 200GB of disk space.

There are many other types of files that are stored along with the VM's virtual disk on the datastore. This could include files representing the systems NVRAM and BIOS, as well as various log files. I would suggest you browse the VM's directory in the datastore and look at what type and size of files exist.